# How do I check if a button exists in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm making a Tic-Tac-Toe program because I'm bored. I am using tkinter, and I have a program that asks which side you want to be, then a window pops up with 9 buttons. When one of these buttons is pressed, an image appears of an **<kbd>X</kbd>** or **<kbd>O</kbd>**. Then the button is deleted. Right now I am making the CPU move section of the program. It will have a loop that is entered when a button is pressed (and deleted). The loop will be broken out of once a random button is invoked. My dilemma is this: I don't know how to check if a button exists, or what the loop should look like. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
import time
import random

tk = Tk()

xoro = input("Choose a side, X or O.")
if xoro == "x":
    side = 0
elif xoro == "o":
    side = 1
else:
    print("Please enter x or o.")

canvas = Canvas(tk, width=498, height=498, background="green")
canvas.pack()
tk.title("Tic-Tac-Toe!")
time.sleep(2)

photo2 = PhotoImage(file="C:\Python34\X.gif")
photo1 = PhotoImage(file="C:\Python34\O.gif")
photolist = [photo2, photo1]

def PlaceImage(photo, x, y, buttontodelete):
    canvas.create_image(x,y, image=photo)
    buttontodelete.destroy()

button1 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!")
button1 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!", bg="green", command=lambda: PlaceImage(photolist[side], 75, 75, button1))
button1.pack()
button1.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=166, width=166)
button1.place(x=0, y=0)
button1.config(highlightbackground="black")

button2 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!")
button2 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!", bg="green", command=lambda: PlaceImage(photolist[side], 75, 241, button2))
button2.pack()
button2.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=166, width=166)
button2.place(x=0, y=166)
button2.config(highlightbackground="black")

button3 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!")
button3 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!", bg="green", command=lambda: PlaceImage(photolist[side], 75, 407, button3))
button3.pack()
button3.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=166, width=166)
button3.place(x=0, y=332)
button3.config(highlightbackground="black")

button4 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!")
button4 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!", bg="green", command=lambda: PlaceImage(photolist[side], 241, 75, button4))
button4.pack()
button4.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=166, width=166)
button4.place(x=166, y=0)
button4.config(highlightbackground="black")

button5 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!")
button5 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!", bg="green", command=lambda: PlaceImage(photolist[side], 241, 241, button5))
button5.pack()
button5.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=166, width=166)
button5.place(x=166, y=166)
button5.config(highlightbackground="black")

button6 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!")
button6 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!", bg="green", command=lambda: PlaceImage(photolist[side], 241, 407, button6))
button6.pack()
button6.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=166, width=166)
button6.place(x=166, y=332)
button6.config(highlightbackground="black")

button7 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!")
button7 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!", bg="green", command=lambda: PlaceImage(photolist[side], 407, 75, button7))
button7.pack()
button7.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=166, width=166)
button7.place(x=332, y=0)
button7.config(highlightbackground="black")

button8 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!")
button8 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!", bg="green", command=lambda: PlaceImage(photolist[side], 407, 241, button8))
button8.pack()
button8.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=166, width=166)
button8.place(x=332, y=166)
button8.config(highlightbackground="black")

button9 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!")
button9 = Button(tk, text="Choose Me!", bg="green", command=lambda: PlaceImage(photolist[side], 407, 407, button9))
button9.pack()
button9.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=166, width=166)
button9.place(x=332, y=332)
button9.config(highlightbackground="black")

buttonlist = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9]
randombutton = random.randint(0, 8)
WHILE BLAH IS TRUE:
    buttonlist[randombutton].invoke()
    BREAK OUT OF LOOP, AND BEGIN USER'S TURN

mainloop()
```

Comment: @NateOlson You may want to review your code, some signs show, there are multiple times assigned a value to the same variable name, which does not make a sense for the problem solution. Similarly there ought to be just one type of geometry-manager user for controlling a layout of the widgets' instances into `tk` instance -- choose { **`.pack()`** | **`.place()`** | **`.grid()`** } whichever one suits best your intentions, but do not mix or chain/repeat one after another as seen above

Answer (score 4):

Instead of deleting the button, just hide it ( with **`.pack_forget()`** method ), and check the visibility of the button ( .visible, I think **`.winfo_viewable()`** method ).

Answer (score 2):

The **`.winfo_exists()`** method tests a widget's existence.

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> app = Tk()
>>> b = Button(text="hello")
>>> b.winfo_exists()
1
>>> b.destroy()
>>> b.winfo_exists()
0
```

Try to avoid loops. You need to raise events and allow the event loop to run as much a possible. In Tk, **`.event_generate()`** method or the **`.after()`** scheduler-method are useful for this.