# Check if a tkinter widget is visible

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to be able to check if a tkinter widget is visible (if its `pack` or `grid` method has been called).

I'm currently doing the following:

```
def is_visible(widget):
    try:
        widget.pack_info()
    except tk.TclError:
        # pack_info raises if pack hasn't been
        # called yet.
        return bool(widget.grid_info())
        # grid_info returns {} if grid hasn't been
        # called yet.
    else:
        return True
```

Is there any way in which I could improve this code, by using a standard widget attribute, or through some other solution that's less 'hacky'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try [`widget.winfo_ismapped()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_ismapped-method) instead :

> Check if the window has been created. This method checks if Tkinter
>   has created a window corresponding to the widget in the underlying
>   window system (an X window, a Windows HWND, etc).
>
> Returns:
>       A true value if a window has been created.

Comment: Is there a difference with [`winfo_viewable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26246540/3337089)?